# Remove results with same id from Elasticsearch search result

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's assume we have a search result with 3 documents. Two of them share a key attribute (product-ID or similar).

Is it possible to remove duplicates from the search result by using Elasticsearch, so that only 2 documents would be returned in that case? I don't want to implement this in application logic as I would still like to use pagination, aggregation, etc. It does not matter which of the two documents with the same id is removed.

Thanks,
Philipp

Edit:

This would be the example in Elasticsearch:

```
PUT /tmp_pd_articles
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name":    { "type": "text" },  
      "articleNumber":  { "type": "keyword"  }
    }
  }
}

PUT /tmp_pd_articles/_doc/1
{
  "name": "My Book 1",
  "articleNumber": "A9781"
}

PUT /tmp_pd_articles/_doc/2
{
  "name": "My Book 1 (with some other title)",
  "articleNumber": "A9781"
}

PUT /tmp_pd_articles/_doc/3
{
  "name": "My Book 2",
  "articleNumber": "A9782"
}


GET /tmp_pd_articles/_search
{
  "query": { "match_all": {} }

}
```

The goal is to write a query that returns only two articles instead of all three:
#1 ("A9781", "My Book 1") **OR** #2 ("A9781", "My Book 1 (with some other title)") **AND**
#3 ("A9782", "My Book 2")

This reduction should be applied because #1 and #2 share the same productNumber "A9781". I wonder whether there is a Elasticsearch query to accomplish this goal.

Comment: can you share some example, your mapping

Comment: I have added an example in the original post.

Comment: its been sometime, please go through answer and lmk if it resolves your issue.

Comment: any luck here??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible using [top-hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html), please use below query to filter the data., note tested it on your mapping and sample data, and it provides your expected data.

```
{
    "size": 0, --> returns only aggregate data, if you want to include all 3 documents remove this size param.
    "aggs": {
        "dedup": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "articleNumber"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "dedup_docs": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And Search result**

```
"aggregations": {
        "dedup": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "A9781",
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "dedup_docs": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 2,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": 1.0,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "tmp_pd_articles",
                                    "_type": "_doc",
                                    "_id": "1",
                                    "_score": 1.0,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "name": "My Book 1",
                                        "articleNumber": "A9781"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "A9782",
                    "doc_count": 1,
                    "dedup_docs": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 1,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": 1.0,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "tmp_pd_articles",
                                    "_type": "_doc",
                                    "_id": "3",
                                    "_score": 1.0,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "name": "My Book 2",
                                        "articleNumber": "A9782"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```